# How to properly handle my routing for a REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, api-design

Apologies if this is a newbie question . How should I go about structuring my REST API (I use Node & Express).

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const recipeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'UserData',
        required: true
    },
    description: String,
    ingredients: [String],
    steps: [String],
    bookmarkNumber: Number,
    likeNumber: Number,
    rating: Number
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Recipe', recipeSchema);
```

While I understand I can use the following for larger scale functions like creating recipes and deleting recipes and e.t.c

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  // Get Recipes
});

router.post('/',checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
  // Create Recipe
});

router.get('/:recipeID', (req, res, next) => {
// Get Specific Recipe
});
```

However I am currently stuck on how to handle the inner details or specific resources. For example : Let's say I would like to add a step to the recipe. Would this specific instance be one where I can put a verb or ? My current idea is to:

```
router.post('/:recipeID/steps',checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
  // Add Steps to recipeID if it exists
});
```

so to basically add urls for the properties and handle them that way since verbs are apparently a REST API sin.

Comment: You should take a look at the `Express 4.x` API Reference. It's really simple to follow and well explained, in your case this section will solve your doubts: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req

Comment: Firstly, Thank you so much for answering my question . My main concern is more about how it's supposed to be done and following Hateoas as I still trying to learn and master REST API structure. I will definitely take a look at the expressjs documentation though. https://restfulapi.net/hateoas/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.post('/:recipeID/:steps',checkAuth, (req, res, next) => {
   if (req.params.steps === 'first') {//based on your requirements

     } else if (condition) {

     }
});
```

However, There are a few rest API rules for different actions.

- `GET /users`: to get user list.
- `GET /users/:userid` : to get information to specific user.
- `POST /users`: to create user.
- `PUT /users` to update specific user information.

It might help you to understand the best approach of design API endpoints.

Comment: Firstly, Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question . So the correct approach is to break down the properties into their own specific nouns and setting up their functions there as required?

Comment: Yeah! If someone tells me to do such kind of functionality I will do as above.

Comment: There is not specific rules/regulation, Its based on you which will be easy for you.

Comment: I have updated my answer please check, It might help you.